# Akka echangetype for consistent hash exchange of RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, akka

Is there a way to use the consistent hash exchange (http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-consistent-hash-exchange/file/default/README.md) of RabbitMQ with Akka amqp? It is easy to use Topic, direct etc. I am wondering if I can specify the exchange type for Akka as x-consistent-hash somehow.
new ExchangeParameters (exchangeName: String, exchangeType: ExchangeType)

right now the supported ExchangeTypes are Direct, Fanout, Match, Topic

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've written any Scala, but it looks like no since ExchangeType is a sealed trait.

If any Akka developers are reading this, it's a *very* good idea to let the developer specify exchange type as an arbitrary string. Providing short cuts for the built in exchange types is nice, but there are lots of interesting new exchange types popping up.

Comment: Yeah that is the key. The consistent hash is something that we could use well in our scenario where we want to round robin the incoming messages on several queues. The idea is not to send the same ones on all the queues ...

Comment: Thanks for confirming my decision to not use Akka's AMQP but to use the Java AMQP client in my Akka application.

Answer (score 0):

Vikas, this is the best I can do at the moment:

https://www.assembla.com/spaces/akka/tickets/1413-support-custom-exchange-types-in-akka-amqp

This means that I'll attempt to have it in teh 1.3-RC2 that will be cut at the end of this week.

I've added CustomExchange("") and it'll be a part of 1.3-RC2

Comment: Sure Viktor, sounds good. We have implemented a home grown round robin for now. Would refactor once the above ticket is closed.